# Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection. Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed (done - 0.0.2.0:3)

Tags: windows, help, bridge, vpn, dns

Can anyone help me out. My Tor Browser was working perfectly fine until I did an update for my windows 7 laptop. Now i keep getting an error message mentioning failing to establish connection.
I have even tried using the pre-installed bridge , which still didn't work. Also my clock time is correct.

Here is the log:

```
06/03/2017 16:04:26.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2017 16:04:26.900 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2017 16:04:26.900 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\Ajid\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 
06/03/2017 16:04:27.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
06/03/2017 16:04:27.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
06/03/2017 16:06:27.700 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2017 16:06:27.700 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2017 16:06:27.800 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
06/03/2017 16:06:29.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2017 16:06:38.300 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2017 16:06:38.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2017 16:06:38.300 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2017 16:06:38.700 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
06/03/2017 16:06:47.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2017 16:06:47.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2017 16:06:47.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2017 16:06:47.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2017 16:06:55.200 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host BBB28DF0F201E706BE564EFE690FE9577DD8386D at 109.105.109.147:13764) 
06/03/2017 16:06:55.200 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
06/03/2017 16:06:55.200 [WARN]  9 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
06/03/2017 16:06:55.200 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
06/03/2017 16:07:02.900 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 11; recommendation warn; host 8DFCD8FB3285E855F5A55EDDA35696C743ABFC4E at 109.105.109.165:10527) 
06/03/2017 16:07:02.900 [WARN] 11 connections have failed: 
06/03/2017 16:07:02.900 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
06/03/2017 16:07:02.900 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
06/03/2017 16:07:02.900 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2017 16:07:02.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/03/2017 16:07:02.900 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/03/2017 16:07:02.900 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 12; recommendation warn; host 7B126FAB960E5AC6A629C729434FF84FB5074EC2 at 192.99.11.54:443) 
06/03/2017 16:07:02.900 [WARN] 12 connections have failed: 
06/03/2017 16:07:02.900 [WARN]  11 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
06/03/2017 16:07:02.900 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
06/03/2017 16:07:02.900 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 13; recommendation warn; host CDF2E852BF539B82BD10E27E9115A31734E378C2 at 192.95.36.142:443) 
06/03/2017 16:07:02.900 [WARN] 16 connections have failed: 
06/03/2017 16:07:02.900 [WARN]  12 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
06/03/2017 16:07:02.900 [WARN]  3 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
06/03/2017 16:07:02.900 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
```